# To call addChildViewController or not to call addChildViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm fairly new to Objective-C and iOS, and I've taken on an application written by someone else. I noticed something that threw me, and I think my question varies slightly from the other questions people have asked about addChildViewController.

Well, the app works just fine.  Rotations work fine.  Everythings good.
So what's the problem?

Well there's a full screen view that holds a bunch of subviews in a side-by-side tiled type of layout.  In other words, all of them have the same full screen parent view, and each are siblings to each other.
Those subviews are each an instance of a `UIViewController`.
I had expected to see those subviews set up like this...

```
DoohickeyController *doohickey = [[DoohickeyController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Doohickey" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:doohickey];
[self.view addSubview:doohickey.view];
```

but instead they simply do this....

```
DoohickeyController *doohickey = [[DoohickeyController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Doohickey" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:doohickey.view];
```

Is there a hard and fast rule about whether or not to call `addChildViewController` when the app appears to work just fine?

Is there any advantage/disadvantage to adding the call to `addChildViewController`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the major design assumptions in UIKit is that the `ViewController` hierarchy will generally be in sync with the `View` hierarchy. Callbacks handling autorotation and size class transitions are passed down through the `ViewController` chain, and if you never create the parent-child relationship between `ViewController`s this system breaks down.

I follow the pattern of (psudo code)

```
//given:
ViewController *a;
ViewController *b;

[a willMoveToViewController:b];
[b addChildViewController:a];
[a didMoveToViewController:b];

[b.view addSubview:a.view];
```

Comment: While I'd tend to agree with that, the app has been working fine without the `addChildViewController` call for over a year, which is leading me to believe that call really isn't necessary in some cases, I just don't know what those cases are.

Comment: It would be noticeable in situations where the child viewcontroller's view needs to be redrawn after a device rotation. It may never hear about the rotation event, and thus never redraw itself.

Comment: Ok.  I'm going to try some debug scenarios and see if I can tell what's going on.  Also, SugaR made an interesting point above in his answer, which I also need to investigate, because my view controller should be going nil, but something is holding on to it, keeping it alive, even though it's a local variable and I'm not adding it as a child controller.

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the reason may be the ownership of your childViewController.

If you `alloc init` it in a function, it is an **auto parameter** inside that function. And when the function returns, your childViewController will be automatically released, and become `nil`.

Meanwhile, the view (`doohickey.view`) of your childViewController, due to you `addSubview` to `self.view`, so it will kept by `self` (viewController). The view still exist in spite of its VC is already `nil`.

So `addChildViewController` let `self` (viewController) keep `doohickey` (subviewController), therefore the ownership of `doohickey` and `doohickey.view` will be unified, and will be released at the same time (after `self` being released).

Comment: That is an interesting thought about the 'alloc init' and actually raises another question.  Yes the allocation is in fact an auto parameter as you suggested, however, it seems that it's NOT disappearing after the function completes because somehow the code in the `alloc init`ed class is still being executed later on in the application... which shouldn't be happening it if had in fact gone nil.  I'm going to research what might be going on there.  Interesting point.

Comment: @user3055655 It doesn't make sense. In my case, I add a childViewController to control my tableview. If I don't add ``addChildViewController`` to ``self`` , the tableView delegates won't be called. Maybe you keep childViewController from other place?

Comment: I'm going to try and figure it out in a debug session.  Maybe the view is holding a weak reference back to it and is somehow keeping it in memory?  I dunno.  Really good question.